# How can I divide up a Pandas column based on its values?

Tags: pandas, slice

I'm playing around with the Titanic's survivor database and I created a separate dataframe that includes only "Fare" and "Cabin" columns.
The "Fare" column is sorted and the dataframe looks like this:

```
      Fare        Cabin
732  0.0000          NaN
413  0.0000          NaN
806  0.0000          A36
266  0.0000          NaN
633  0.0000          NaN
674  0.0000          NaN
815  0.0000         B102
372  0.0000  B52 B54 B56
21   3.1708          NaN
378  4.0125          NaN
872  5.0000  B51 B53 B55
```

The fare increases all the way too 500.0000. 
So the tail of the database looks something like this:

```
     Fare        Cabin
679  512.3292  B51 B53 B55
737  512.3292         B101
258  512.3292          NaN
343  512.3292  B51 B53 B55
152       NaN          NaN
```

I want to break up this dataframe by the 100s. So one dataframe would consist of Fare values from 0 ~100, the next one would be 101 ~200 and so on. I played around with groupby but I got nowhere. I'm stumped. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the `df`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(Fare=np.arange(500), Cabin='a'))
```

use `pd.cut` to get categorical groupints

```
cut = pd.cut(df.Fare, np.arange(7) * 100, include_lowest=True)
```

This is enough to use `pd.get_dummies`

```
pd.get_dummies(cut)
```

or you can use it to group by

```
gp = df.groupby(cut)
```

Comment: Thanks., first time I have seen cut.  I got it working with groupby and cut. When I used get_dummies, I was only getting boolean values (1's and 0's).

Answer (score 2):

You could simply write:

```
df100 = df[(df.Fare < 100)]
df200 = df[(df.Fare > 100) & (df.Fare < 200)]
```

and so on

Comment: Thanks. Would there be a way to iterate this?